# Highcharts plotBackgroundColor on spider chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to create a spider chart that looks like this [example spider chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h1H1.png).

I am nearly there, but cannot seem to apply the blue background color to the largest (or any) heptagon. I'm assuming the heptagons are paths from the x/y axis and not actual shapes which is why I can't just apply a fill. The closest I can get is using 'plotBackgroundColor' on the chart itself, but this isn't right.

[My CodePen attempt](https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/RZEqWW) (Ignore the slider)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   colors: ['#f78200', '#90ee7e'],
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'area',
        plotBorderColor: '#f78200',
        plotBackgroundColor: '#3d4d5d'
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Current equity exposure',
        x: -80
    },

    pane: {
        size: '80%',
        plotBackgroundColor: '#3d4d5d'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['UK', 'North America', 'Japan', 'Europe ex-UK', 'Pacific ex-Japan', 'Emerging markets', 'Global'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0,
        gridLineColor: '#263542',
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
            // formatter: function() {
            //     return this.value + '%';
            // }
        },
        gridLineColor: '#263542',
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}"><strong>{point.y:.2f}%</strong><br/>'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        layout: 'vertical',
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Exposure',
        data: [22.2, 10.4, 3.8, 5.6, 2.2, 4.7, 7.1],
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        fillColor: 'rgba(247, 130, 0, 0.2)'
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create additional area series which will work as a background. All you need to do is to fill it with values equal `yAxis.max`, set `showInLegend` with false value and disable mouse tracking. You can also disable its `animation` and `markers`. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.showInLegend
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.enableMouseTracking
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.animation
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.marker

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2w3cqntq/